# fastest way to load 1.5 million images into a dask cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I'm trying to persist 1.5 million images to a dask cluster as a dask array, and then get some summary stats. I'm following an [image processing tutorial from @mrocklin's blog](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/17/dask-images) and have edited my script to be a minimally reproducible example:

```
import time
import dask
import dask.array as da

import numpy as np
from distributed import Client

client = Client()

def get_imgs(num_imgs):
    def get():
        arr = np.random.randint(2000, size=(3, 120, 120)).flatten()
        return arr

    delayed_get = dask.delayed(get)

    return [da.from_delayed(delayed_get(), shape=(3 * 120 * 120,), dtype=np.uint16) for num in range(num_imgs)]

imgs = get_imgs(1500000)
imgs = da.stack(imgs, axis=0)
client.persist(imgs)
```

The `persist` step causes my jupyter process to crash. Is that because the `persist` step causes a bunch of operations to be done on each object in the collection, and the collection is too large to fit in memory? So I use `scatter` instead:

```
start = time.time()
imgs_future = client.scatter(imgs, broadcast=True)
print(time.time() - start)
```

But the jupyter process crashes, or the network connection to the scheduler gets lost.

[image]

So I tried breaking up the `scatter` step:

```
st = time.time()

chunk_size = 50000
chunk_num = 0
chunk_futures = []
start = 0
end = start + chunk_size
is_last_chunk = False

for dataset in client.list_datasets():
    client.unpublish_dataset(dataset)

while True:
    cst = time.time()
    chunk = imgs[start:end]
    cst1 = time.time()

    if start == 0:
        print('loaded chunk in', cst1 - cst)

    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break

    chunk_future = client.scatter(chunk)
    chunk_futures.append(chunk_future)
    dataset_name = "chunk_{}".format(chunk_num)
    client.publish_dataset(**{dataset_name: chunk_future})

    if start == 0:
        print('submitted chunk in', time.time() - cst1)
    start = end

    if is_last_chunk:
        break

    chunk_num += 1
    end = start + chunk_size
    if end > len(image_paths_to_submit):
        is_last_chunk = True
        end = len(image_paths_to_submit)

    if start == end:
        break

    if chunk_num % 5 == 0:
        print('chunk_num', chunk_num, 'start', start)

print('completed in', time.time() - st)
```

But this approach results in the connection being lost as well. What's the recommended approach to persisting a large image dataset in a cluster in an asynchronous way?

I've looked at the [delayed best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html) and what jumps out at me is that I may be using too many tasks? So maybe I need to do more batching in each `get()` call.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that because the persist step causes a bunch of operations to be done on each object in the collection, and the collection is too large to fit in memory?

The best way to find out if this is the case is by using Dask's dashboard. 
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html#dashboard

> I'm following an image processing tutorial from @mrocklin's blog

That post is somewhat old.  You may also want to take a look at this more recent post: 
https://blog.dask.org/2019/06/20/load-image-data

> I've looked at the delayed best practices and what jumps out at me is that I may be using too many tasks? So maybe I need to do more batching in each get() call.

Yes, that might be a problem.  If you can keep the number of tasks down that would be nice.

Comment: Ok. The 2019 tutorial doesn't discuss how to persist the data to a cluster and run computations on the cluster. Is there specific guidance on how to do that?

Comment: Things are no different with Dask if you run locally or attached to a cluster.

Comment: My understanding from the documentation is that the default scheduler is a local multithreaded scheduler, and in order to use the distributed scheduler, you have to send compute to the scheduler via the client: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html Is there another way to configure the scheduler to use the distributed scheduler, possibly with `dask.config.set`?